# How can I add a field to an existing POJO when parsing it to json using jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Pojo class that looks like this

```
@Table(name = "attachments")
public class Attachment {

@Column(name="id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "uuid")
private String uuid;

@Column(name = "customer_id")
private Integer customerId;

@Column(name = "size")
private Integer size;

@Column(name = "uploaded_to_minio")
private Boolean uploaded;

@Column(name = "created_at")
private LocalDateTime created;

@Column(name = "updated_at")
private LocalDateTime updated;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@JsonAppend(
        attrs = {
                @JsonAppend.Attr(value = "DownloadLink")
        }
)
public static class DownloadLink {}
// Getters, Setters omitted
}
```

When I call a REST endpoint, example: localhost:8080/attachments/2500 I get a Json like this. (2500 is customer id in this context and the endpoint returns a List<>)

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "uuid": "8980560a-f9af-4ce5-80a6-9da384f8f886",
    "customerId": 2500,
    "size": 336430,
    "uploaded": false,
    "created": {
        "hour": 11,
        "minute": 24,
        "second": 8,
        "nano": 0,
        "dayOfYear": 311,
        "dayOfWeek": "WEDNESDAY",
        "month": "NOVEMBER",
        "dayOfMonth": 7,
        "year": 2018,
        "monthValue": 11,
        "chronology": {
            "calendarType": "iso8601",
            "id": "ISO"
        }
    },
    "updated": null,
    "name": "image_2500_20130916_11_41_17.jpeg"
}
    // other json omitted
```

It successfully returns a List<> of `Attachment`. Now, What I want to do is add a field "downloadLink" as `JsonAppend` when individual id is called, like this localhost:8080/attachments/2500/7

```
{
"id": 7,
"uuid": "8980560a-f9af-4ce5-80a6-9da384f8f886",
"customerId": 2500,
"size": 336430,
"uploaded": false,
"created": [
    2018,
    11,
    7,
    11,
    24,
    8
],
"updated": null,
"name": "image_2500_20130916_11_41_17.jpeg",
"DownloadLink": "http://127.0.0.1:9000/test/8980560a-f9af-4ce5-80a6-9da384f8f886/image_2500_20130916_11_41_17.jpeg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=EZXTCHKE2YHUNRPI8JCL%2F20181108%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20181108T101712Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=f45023cda340afcb9ba49343c0cf1a5bbb1577e8fcdb52ef59f7c2f25f967874"
}
```

I can acheive this by a method that looks like this:

```
@GET
@Path("customers/{customerId}/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getAttachmentById(@PathParam("customerId") Integer customerId, @PathParam("id") Integer id) throws Exception {
    Attachment attachment = attachmentService.getAttachment(customerId, id);
    String downloadlink = minioFileServer.getDownloadLinkForFile("test", attachment.getUuid(), attachment.getName());
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());        
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.addMixIn(Attachment.class, Attachment.DownloadLink.class);
    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writerFor(Attachment.class).withAttribute("DownloadLink", downloadlink);
    String jsonString = writer.writeValueAsString(attachment);             
    return jsonString;
}
```

What I really want to do is to return an Attachment instance itself and not String. When I tried doing so like this:

```
attachment = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Attachment.class);
return attachment;
```

It gives me plain Json without downloadlink as in first json. When I'm returning String, it gives me what I need, but when I return Pojo it's not showing downloadlink. Can anyone please help me pointing to the right direction? I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: You could change the service which return the JSON as string and get the Attachment object you want. Remember in the end the JSON is nothing more than a MAP with keys and values as Strings.

Comment: In my case, the easiest solution I found was to simply add a field `downloadLink` in the Pojo, annotate it with `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` to simply have it invisible from the Json when the field is null